# ORA-00911: invalid character issue?

Tags: oracle, plsql

So I have procedure that compiles without issue, but when I run it it returns:

```
Error report -
ORA-00911: invalid character
ORA-06512: at "MYDATABASE.MY_PROCEDURE", line 4
ORA-06512: at line 2
00911. 00000 -  "invalid character"
*Cause:    identifiers may not start with any ASCII character other than
           letters and numbers.  $#_ are also allowed after the first
           character.  Identifiers enclosed by doublequotes may contain
           any character other than a doublequote.  Alternative quotes
           (q'#...#') cannot use spaces, tabs, or carriage returns as
           delimiters.  For all other contexts, consult the SQL Language
           Reference Manual.
*Action:
```

Here's procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MY_PROCEDURE
IS
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE CHILD_TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT FK_CHILD_TABLE_PARENT_TABLE FOREIGN KEY (PARENT_TABLE_ID) REFERENCES PARENT_TABLE(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE;';
END;
```

Here's how I call it :)

```
BEGIN
MY_PROCEDURE;
END;
```

I can mention that there's no fault in

```
ALTER TABLE CHILD_TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT FK_CHILD_TABLE_PARENT_TABLE FOREIGN KEY (PARENT_TABLE_ID) REFERENCES PARENT_TABLE(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Because it runs without issue outside of procedure body :)

Comment: remove ; inside an execute immediate query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `;` inside a query in `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MY_PROCEDURE
IS
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE CHILD_TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT FK_CHILD_TABLE_PARENT_TABLE FOREIGN KEY (PARENT_TABLE_ID) REFERENCES PARENT_TABLE(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE';
END;
```